# VHDL Error [no choices for 'U' to 'X]' & [can't match character literal..]

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ghdl

I'm new to VHDL and I am trying to generate these pulses compt, etat, SORTIE, here is the code:

```
Library ieee; Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity EXO is
port (CLK, EN: in bit; SORTIE: out bit);
end entity;

architecture EXXO of EXO is

signal compt : integer range 0 to 7 ;
signal etat : std_logic;

begin

    process (CLK)
    begin
        if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
            if EN = '1' then compt <= compt + 1;
                case etat is
                    when '0' => if compt = 3 then compt <= '0'; SORTIE <= '1'; etat <= '1'; end if;
                    when '1' => if compt = 2 then compt <= 0; SORTIE <= '0'; etat <= '0'; end if;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

When I run **ghdl -s ha.vhdl** in terminal, I get this error:

```
ha.vhdl:20:40:error: no choices for 'U' to 'X'
ha.vhdl:19:32:error: no choices for 'Z' to '-'
ha.vhdl:20:79:error: can't match character literal '0' with type integer
```

**EDIT**: I changed **signal etat : std_logic** to **signal etat : bit** eliminating other possibilities. the problem was solved bu now gtkwave doesn't display anything

[Screenshot of GTKWAVE after edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRDn.png)

```
Library ieee; Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity EXO1 is
port (CLK, EN: in bit; SORTIE: out bit);
end entity;

architecture EXXO of EXO1 is

signal compt : integer range 0 to 7 ;
signal etat : bit;

begin

    process (CLK)
    begin
        if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
            if EN = '1' then
                compt <= compt + 1;
                case etat is
                    when '0' => if compt = 3 then compt <= 0; SORTIE <= '1'; etat <= '1'; end if;
                    when '1' => if compt = 2 then compt <= 0; SORTIE <= '0'; etat <= '0'; end if;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: `case` statement doesn't cover all possible combinations of `etat ` which is `std_logic`. Use `case others =>` to cover all possible states of `std_logic`

Comment: The cause of this error - `ha.vhdl:20:79:error: can't match character literal '0' with type integer` - is clear if you compare line 20 with line 19.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I changed **signal etat : std_logic** to **signal etat : bit** eliminating other possibilities. the problem now is that _gtkwave_ doesn't display anything (I have edited the post and included a screenshot )

Comment: @ Matthew Taylor Please take a look Sir to the Edit

Comment: You edited your question removing s [mcve]. The code in the question no longer duplicates the problem.

Comment: @user1155120 No, The first code is exactly the same, I didn't modify it, nor modified the error it produces. It still duplicates the problem 100%. The edit only suggests a solution for it.

Comment: `signal etat : bit;`  That type bit used to be std_logic - **EDIT**: I changed signal etat : std_logic to signal etat : bit `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ Matthew Taylor and @ Rakend

`case` statement doesn't cover all possible combinations of `etat`  which is `std_logic`

Instead of using `case others =>` to cover all possible states of `std_logic`, I changed `signal etat : std_logic` to `signal etat : bit` eliminating other possibilities, meaning that the signal takes only two possibilities 0 or 1. Hence the question at hand is resolved.